# Partition not mounting from fstab

Tags: partition, mount, fstab

I have mounted a partition and add it to `fstab` file and then rebooted but I see that the partition is not mounted although it was added to `fstab`.

What is wrong, and how can I solve it?
`fstab` line:
`/dev/xvdf   /dev/xvdb1  ext3    defaults        0   0`

Comment: Edit your question and add the fstab line to it. Also, when changing `/etc/fstab` don't reboot to test it. Use `mount -a` an check if it worked.

Comment: What is `/dev/xvdf` and `/dev/xvdb1`? What is the output to `cat /proc/partitions`? What device do you want to mount and what should the mountpoint be (where should it appear in the file tree)?

Comment: Both of these are good comments, and I wanted to second the 1st suggestion.  Using `mount -a` is almost always a good habit to check the validity of fstab.  The reason it is good is that it will immediately list any errors it finds, so you not only know whether the file is valid, but if it isn't, you know what the errors are, which, of course, is a nice first step to solving the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Something is very fishy about that fstab-line:

```
/dev/xvdf /dev/xvdb1 ext3 defaults 0 0
```

Normally they have the format:

```
/dev/device /mnt/mountpoint fs flags stuffINeverRemember
```

Basically, what this line does or tries is mounting `/dev/xvdf` onto the *directory* `/dev/xvdb1`. I think you misunderstood how `/etc/fstab` works. You most likely want something like this:

```
/dev/xvdb1 /mnt/ ext3 defaults 0 0
```

In particular, note that the mount point (`/mnt` in this example) must be an existing directory, it will not be created for you.